# Prove that the product of the entries of an $n$-dimensional vector induces a linear $n$-application

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

I want to show that the aplication

$$p: \mathbb{R} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$

defined by

$$p(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})=\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$$

is a $n$-linear form.
Let's see in particular, for example, if it is bilinear

$$p(\alpha u+\beta v, w)=((\alpha u+\beta v) \cdot w)=\alpha(u \cdot w)+\beta(v \cdot w)=\alpha p(u, w)+\beta p(v, w)$$

Analogously

$$p(u, \alpha v + \beta w)=\alpha p(u, v) + \beta p(u, w)$$

For the first $n$-values, the result is even trivial, but how can I generalize this expression to run through the $n$-terms? any help is welcome!

Comment: Just prove it directly for an arbitrary $x_k$.  It's a consequence of distributivity.

Comment: @CyclotomicField something like this?...$p(x_{1}, \dots, x_{j}+ \lambda x'_{j}, \dots, x_{k})=p(x_{1}, \dots, x_{j}, \dots, x_{k})+ \lambda p(x_{1}, \dots, x'_{j}, \dots, x_{k})$ Or how would be the correct writing of the test, help me a little bit with it? thanks!

Comment: You've got the right adea. I'd just use $u$ and $v$ like you did for the bilinear part to avoid clutter and index chasing. You'll need to use the properties of $\prod x_i$ to prove it but it's straightforward.